# Wrong bitmap gets attached to imageview inside viewpager

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, android-viewpager

I am making an application where I need to display PDF pages inside ViewPager. We create Bitmap from each PDF page and then set it to ImageView. Creating bitmap is expensive process so I decided to cache bitmap once it gets created. This also improved the performance in terms of memory and loading bitmap. Since this is not a http request so I couldn't use any image caching library like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). Instead I have used google's [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DisplayingBitmaps) sample and added the conversion logic of PDF page to Bitmap here.But the problem is when I swipe pages wrong bitmaps gets attached to wrong ImageViews.

For example I am swiping to page no. 5 and before the bitmap loads if I move back to 3 then the bitmap which suppose to attached to 5th page gets wrongly attached to 3rd page.

I tried a lot but couldn't fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Share some code...

Comment: You can follow [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DisplayingBitmaps). I have used this only.

Comment: It's working fine with http request.

Comment: Issue may be with your view pager implementation logic

Comment: Any idea how to fix it.

Comment: try setting some text instead of image to conform issue is not arise from image loading